Config SSL for q2 jpos server
<server class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer" logger="Q2" name="xml-server-8100" realm="xml-server-8100">
    <attr name="port" type="java.lang.Integer">8100</attr>
    <server-socket-factory class="org.jpos.iso.GenericSSLSocketFactory">
        <property name="clientauth" value="true"/>
        <property name="serverauth" value="true"/>
        <property name="keystore" value="/home/nghiango1/Documents/ISO8583/gateway/ssl/client-keystore.jks"/>
        <property name="storepassword" value="client-keystore-password"/>
        <property name="keypassword" value="client-keystore-password"/>
    </server-socket-factory>
    <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.XMLChannel" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.XMLPackager" type="server"
             logger="Q2" realm="xml-server-8100">
        <property name="timeout" value="180000"/>
        <property name="maxConnections" value="100"/>
    </channel>
    <request-listener class="org.jpos.iso.IncomingListener" logger="Q2" realm="incoming-request-listener">
        <property name="queue" value="TXNMGR"/>
        <property name="ctx.DESTINATION" value="jPOS-AUTORESPONDER"/>
    </request-listener>
</server>

how to config trust-store.jks
I don't know how to configure ssl details for jpos q2 server. Does jpos use keystore.jks and truststore.jke in a single jks file?

Have you looked at section 5.2 of the programmer's guide?
http://jpos.org/doc/proguide.pdf
